# How to not have to "define" optional method parameters?

Tags: typescript

I read that we can make optional method parameters, but when calling a method which has optional parameters, you still have to fill them with `undefined`, which is kinda strange and boring at same time.

Is there any workaround that?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class App {
    constructor(a?:string, b?:string, c?:boolean){}
}

let app:App = new App('a', 'need to fill b to fill c', true)
```

**Error I get when trying to skip the middle parameter**
[image: Error I get when trying to skip the middle parameter]

Comment: You definitely don't have to explicitly fill optional parameters, unless you're defining it wrong or using a really weird linter or something. Can you provide a code example of what you mean?

Comment: Sure, here is the example @JohnMontgomery:

`class App {
    constructor(a?:string, b?:string, c?:string){}
}

let app:App = new App('a', 'need to fill be', 'c)`

I need to fill the b optional parameter in order to fill the c, but only wanted to fill a and c paramater.

Comment: Edit your question, don't add it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip optional parameters *as long as the ones you're skipping are at the end of the parameter list*. TypeScript doesn't have parameter labels, so it has to rely on the order of the parameters to know which is which - if you skip one in the middle, how is it supposed to know that?

So if you wanted to leave out the value for `c`, or both `b` and `c`, or even all three, you'd be fine. Otherwise, you're going to have to deal with it.

Another option would be to pass in an object as the parameter, since the keys are labeled rather than ordered so you can skip any you want:

```
class App {
    constructor(args: {a?:string, b?:string, c?:string}){} 
}

let app:App = new App({a: 'a', c: 'c'})
```

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't seem right what you describe. Anyway, important rule: optional parameters can't be followed by required parameters. Here's how to do it:

```
public mymethod(P:number, p1:number = 0):void
{

}

this.mymethod(0);
this.mymethod(0, 1);
```